# Three.js Physijs.BoxMesh rotateOnAxis

Tags: three.js, physijs

Im trying to rotate a BoxMesh around its Axis.

Without `Physijs.Scene.simulation()` rotateOnAxis works, but with the simulation it doesn't work. With the simulation it does move around its position.

```
    this.player.__dirtyPosition = true;
    // move forwards/backwards/left/right
    if ( this.keyboard.pressed("W") )
        this.player.translateZ( -moveDistance );
    if ( this.keyboard.pressed("S") )
        this.player.translateZ(  moveDistance );
    if ( this.keyboard.pressed("Q") )
        this.player.translateX( -moveDistance );
    if ( this.keyboard.pressed("E") )
        this.player.translateX(  moveDistance );

    // rotate left/right/up/down
    if ( this.keyboard.pressed("A") )
    {
        this.player.rotateOnAxis( new THREE.Vector3(0,1,0), rotateAngle);
    }
    if ( this.keyboard.pressed("D") )
    {
        this.player.rotateOnAxis( new THREE.Vector3(0,1,0), -rotateAngle);
    }
```

So W,S,Q,E works but A,D doesn't work with `Physijs.Scene.simulation()`, A,D does work without `Physijs.Scene.simulation()`. Any ideas?

[sourcecode](https://bitbucket.org/mhoogstraten/myscene/src)

**Edit solved:

It is obvious that `this.player.__dirtyPosition = true;` only allows you to change the position, but not the rotation, i looked inside the code and searched for something similar so i found that there is also a `this.player.__dirtyRotation = true;` which solved my problems! =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is obvious that this.player.__dirtyPosition = true; only allows you to change the position, but not the rotation, i looked inside the code and searched for something similar so i found that there is also a this.player.__dirtyRotation = true; which solved my problems! =)